# Why is the syntax of the arguments in this ts function incorrect?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm exporting this function as part of a module like this:

```
module.exports = { 
    x: 1,
    execute: async (client: any, message: any):Promise<any> => {
        // . . .
    }
}
```

but I get told that I'm missing a ) when I try to compile and run.

```
execute: async (client: any, message: any):Promise<any> => {
                    ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I have tried to create this in a normal function a la `const x = () = {}` and export it just by name but it gave me the same error. What steps do I need to take to fix this?

Comment: `x = 1` should be `x: 1`. I assume that might lead to further syntax issues. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwA4gE5QjAvDA3jAKBmJgQC4YBGAGiJMTmAFco4KBDCATzGBgApgAGwCWcMFA5gu1GAFs4ECOwDmbGO2kBKMgAVUIOSIhwAPJq4A+bNdx0SJAPSOYAOjdv7MAL4FvQA)

Comment: Also, `const x = () = => {}` is wrong, it should be `const x = () => {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is where you're defining the 'x' property,

This

```
module.exports = { 
    x = 1, // x = 1 is a syntax error
    execute: async (client: any, message: any):Promise<any> => {
        // . . .
    }
}
```

Needs to become this

```
module.exports = { 
    x: 1, // fixed
    execute: async (client: any, message: any):Promise<any> => {
        // . . .
    }
}
```

Regarding your comment about creating x as a function, you also have an error.

This

```
const x = () = => {}
```

Needs to become

```
const x = () => {}
```

Comment: I was in a rush when writing the question and mistyped : as =, my code does in fact use a colon: 
sry